# mscorlib.dll exception in string.Contains

Tags: exception, contains, mscorlib

I am getting mscorlib.dll exception on the first line of part_1 method but only when I write for example ("xx"). With only one ("x") is everything ok. I know that it is connected to file which I read but do not know why app crash due to so "small" change and how to fix it. File has got over 300 000 lines.
Code is :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int lines_number = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(@"path_to_folder"))
        {
            string file_name = "something";
            string ip = "something";
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllText(f).Split('\n');
            part_1(lines_number, lines, ip);
            lines_number = 0;
        }
    }

    private void part_1(int i, string[] lines, string ip)
    {
        if (lines[i].Contains("xx"))
        {
            lines_number++;
            string program = "something";
            string start = "something";
            part_2(lines_number, program, start, lines, ip);
        }
        else
        {
            lines_number++;
            if (lines_number < lines.Count())
                part_1(lines_number, lines, ip);
        }
    }
    private void part_2(int i, string program, string start, string[] lines, string ip)
    {
        if (lines[i+1].Contains("something"))
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

}
```

I cleared the code from everything which should not be needed for this purpose.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: The part1() method is recursive with an O(n) stack depth.  A recursive algorithm should only be used for O(logN) algorithms or a strictly bound depth or a guaranteed tail recursion optimization.  Your code and data provides none of those guarantees.  Use a foreach loop instead.

Comment: Yes, it should be solution. I did not did it this way becuase code would look very messy and might be hard to work with it some time after. Also I need check next line in part_2 as you can see"lines[i+1]" which is not such easy in foreach. Recursion have to be stopped by "if(lines_number < lines.Count())". So I just hope(d?) that there might be another way...?